# Node.js | Adding values to array entries while async iteration not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, async.js

This might be a dumb question, but I hope I can still get help from you guys. I have this function which calculates the win chance for each bet:

```
module.exports.getWinner = function(round, callback) {
  async.eachOf(round.bets, (bet, id, cbBet) => {
    round.bets[id].chance = (round.bets[id].value / round.value) * 100;
    cbBet();
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(new Error(`Error iterating through bets array`));
      return;
    }
    console.log(round.bets);
  });
}
```

I am using the async library to asynchronously iterate over my array (round.bets). For each bet in that array I calculate a win chance which I then attach to the bet. But when I console.log the array after the iteration finished the chance is not attached to the bet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your `console.log()` is inside your error handler.  Is that a typo?

Comment: No, that is the callback of the async function. It only passes an error, that's why it may be confusing

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

My mongoose model for the round.bets[x] object didn't include a "chance" field. That's why the chance wasn't saving to the object.